# Creating appropriate typings for node-simple-schema

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, meteor

I am atttempting to use node-simple-schema in my Meteor/Angular2/Typescript project and running into an issue with the typings.  I tried opening an issue at the package to no avail:

https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema/issues/90

from what I posted there:
"Steps to reproduce:
- Create a brand new project via 'git clone https://github.com/bsliran/angular2-meteor-base'
- Prepare Packages

```
meteor update
meteor update --all-packages
meteor npm update
meteor remove insecure
meteor remove autopublish
meteor add aldeed:collection2-core
meteor npm install --save simpl-schema
meteor add aldeed:schema-deny
meteor add aldeed:schema-index
meteor add accounts-password
meteor add alanning:roles
```

- Create file '/both/models/shared.schema.ts'
- Contents of file:

  import { SimpleSchema } from 'simpl-schema';

  export const MyValidationContext = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
      type: String
  }
  });
- Generates Error:

> .meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.13aht4s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
>   W20170403-05:53:05.591(0)? (STDERR) throw(ex);
>   W20170403-05:53:05.591(0)? (STDERR) ^ W20170403-05:53:05.591(0)?
>   (STDERR) W20170403-05:53:05.592(0)? (STDERR) TypeError:
>   simpl_schema_1.SimpleSchema is not a function
>   W20170403-05:53:05.592(0)? (STDERR) at
>   meteorInstall.both.models.shared.schema.js
>   (both/models/shared.schema.ts:6:35) W20170403-05:53:05.592(0)?
>   (STDERR) at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:197:9)
>   W20170403-05:53:05.592(0)? (STDERR) at require
>   (packages/modules-runtime.js:120:16) W20170403-05:53:05.592(0)?
>   (STDERR) at server/main.ts:4:22 W20170403-05:53:05.593(0)? (STDERR) at
>   /var/webapps/schema/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:303:34
>   W20170403-05:53:05.593(0)? (STDERR) at Array.forEach (native)
>   W20170403-05:53:05.594(0)? (STDERR) at Function..each..forEach
>   (/home/blah/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.13aht4s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11) W20170403-05:53:05.594(0)? (STDERR) at
>   /var/webapps/schema/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
>   W20170403-05:53:05.594(0)? (STDERR) at
>   /var/webapps/schema/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:352:5
>   W20170403-05:53:05.595(0)? (STDERR) at Function.run
>   (/var/webapps/schema/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)

- Expected behavior:
  Named validation context exported for use elsewhere within the application.
- What else I tried

1: `dts-gen -m simpl-schema`

2: `typings install --save meteor-simple-schema --source global --global` which imports the old, deprecated meteor-simple-schema typings.  From there I copied the typings from /typings/globals/meteor-simple-schema and declared a new module simpl-schema in /typings.d.ts, where I pasted them.  A few tweaks later, I'm mostly through all the compiler errors except the most important one:

TypeError: simpl_schema_1.SimpleSchema is not a function

Is there something I've missed or done incorrectly in my setup to get to this point?  Is there a set of typings out there I haven't discovered yet?  Is there a more straightforward way to declare the typings for the module?  I've resigned myself to having to do it manually but can't figure out how to write the type that allows for `new SimpleSchema`, apparently.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried without the accolades, as shown on the [README](https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema)?

```
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
```

The package exports a [default member](https://github.com/aldeed/node-simple-schema/blob/master/lib/main.js).

Comment: I had; I got an error that it didn't export a default member tho I agree you can see one exported in /simpl-schema/main.js.  Trying it again now, just to be safe.

Comment: both/collections/shared/shared.schema.ts (8, 8): Module '"simpl-schema"' has no default export.  But you know what, _it isn't crashing_, it's just a compiler error.  I wonder why the compiler can't see that, but it does appear to be working and Meteor loads and runs now which means I can troubleshoot further...thanks for getting me to try that again.

Comment: Your typings definition likely do not mention that default export. TypeScript relies on these typings for code analysis, but bad typings do not affect the underlying JS code.